# Why is self.tableView nil when I (think I) set it up correctly?

Tags: ios, uitableview, null

I have added my  custom UICollectionViewController as an object (A) to the interface builder, and given it the proper custom class.
this EOCollectionViewController is also an IBOutlet in my main Viewcontroller

I have added the UICollectionView to the main view of the application.

I have made all the links possible. UICollectionView has the object (A) as a delegate and a datasource.
The object (A) has the UICollectionView linked to the view property. (not the self.collectionView property, as this is not there)

It all works well. Collection view get's filled. The CollectionViewController resides in the property of my main view controller.

Only the self.collectionView is nil...when I try to reach it from within the UICollectionViewController.

My first guess is that "extra" UIControllers used in IB do not get initalized in the same way. I also tested, and viewDidLoad and init never get called for these extra objects.

Attached the header of EONoteController (and the IBOutlet added as a work-around)

```
@interface EONoteController : UICollectionViewController<UIGestureRecognizerDelegate>{

    __weak IBOutlet UICollectionView *cvNotes;
}
@property (nonatomic) EDAMNotebook* notebook;
@property id <EODragHandler> draghandler;
@end
```

My first guess was to "fix" it, in the viewDidLoad, as follows
self.collectionView = self.view, but viewDidLoad never get's called.

What am i Missing?

Comment: stupid question: Have you checked that the IBOutlet is connected correctly in the XIB/Storyboard?

Comment: it is properly connected. I feel these ad-hoc instantiated controllers in another controller do not go through the same life cycle as other controllers